# PHP weird comparison

Tags: php

I've got two inputs in registration form, one with login, one with password. After calling AJAX I'm trying to validate those data and I'm using function below:

```
function test_input($data) {

if( $data == $_POST["login"] && $data == "" ){
    $GLOBALS["message"] .= "<p>Empty login.</p>";
    return;
    }

elseif( $data == $_POST["pwd"] && $data == "" ){
    $GLOBALS["message"] .= "<p>Empty password.</p>";
    return;
    }
echo 'Good job.';
}
```

When I click submit button without writing anything I've got answer:

```
Empty login
Empty login
```

When I write something in one of them or both of them validation's ok. Why?

Edit - Missing code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $login = test_input($_POST["login"]);
  $pwd = test_input($_POST["pwd"]);
if($message!= ""){
    echo $message;
    }
  else{
    echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is `$data`? and what is its actual purpose? And how are you calling your `test_input()` function?

Comment: You aren't calling it using `test_input($_POST["login"]); test_input($_POST["pwd"]);` are you?

Comment: Are there supposed to be two equal signs in the beginning of the if statement?

Comment: @MarkBaker It's a bad way to call this?

Comment: It's certainly the wrong function that you've written to be called that way

Comment: OK, but I still don't know how to repair this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps refactor it something like:

```
function test_input($data, $field) {
    if( $field == "login" && $data == "" ){
        return "<p>Empty login.</p>";
    }
    elseif( $field == "pwd" && $data == "" ){
        return "<p>Empty password.</p>";
    }
    echo 'Good job.';
}
```

and

```
$message = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $message .= test_input($_POST["login"], "login");
    $message .= test_input($_POST["pwd"], "pwd");
    if($message!= ""){
        echo $message;
    }
    else{
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why my code is wrong? Why I can't use $_POST['something']?

Comment: Because inside your version of the function, there's nothing to differentiate whether the `$data` value you're passing in is the `$_POST["login"]` or the `$_POST["pwd"]` value unless they're correct, and different... and as you're checking for incorrect values here, they don't match up

Comment: Get a pen and paper (or a debugger), and work through your code line by line looking at the values and working out the comparisons that are being performed at each stage of your function... it's easier to do on paper until you're experienced enough to do it in your head